# Dynamically populated select menus in Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

In a view I have a couple of select menus that are populated by data from two separate tables.

Looking for a way to populate the second select menu depending on the value of the first.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('company', 'Company')}}
    <select selected="" class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
        @foreach($company as $key)
            <option value="">{{$key->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('department', 'Department')}}
    <select selected="" class="form-control" id="department" name="department">
        @foreach($department as $key)
            <option =value"">{{$key->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

This feels like something that shouldn't be too hard, but have yet to find any good information about it.

Comment: You have to use javascript to do this. How do you define which set of values are going to be loaded in second select?

Comment: Depending on which company is selected a list of departments belonging to the company selected is to be loaded to the second select menu if thats that you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is using javascript. The main idea is to have a partial view with the second select and then call it when the user change something in the first select.
To do this, you need to have two views. The main view will have a call to the second view with a default collection of departments:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('company', 'Company')}}
    <select selected="" class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
        @foreach($company as $key)
            <option value="">{{$key->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div id="second-select" class="form-group">
    @include('contents.partial', ['department' => $department])
</div>
```

The second view (contents.partial) will print the form:

```
{{Form::label('department', 'Department')}}
<select selected="" class="form-control" id="department" name="department">
    @foreach($department as $key)
        <option =value"">{{$key->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Then you'll need a route to call a function to render the second view based on some value:

```
Route::get('/get/content/{value}', 'ContentController@getContent');
```

And the function to render the view in ContentController:

```
public function getContent(Request $request, $value)
{
    $department = Department::where('value', $value)->get();

    return view('contents.partial', [
        'department' => $department
    ])->render();
}
```

And to call this, you need a javascript/jquery to identify the change in the select and fire the function in controller

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setListener();    
    });

    function setListener() {
        $('#company').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.get( "/get/content/"+value, function( data ) {
                $('#second-select').empty();
                $('#second-select').append(data);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is the main idea, ok?

Comment: Implemented your example, but the partial view still loads all the department values independent of the previous company selected. Does it have something to do with the $department list passed with the partial view?

Comment: The first time the page opens, it will load the default departments. But when you select an option, it should fire a change event and call getContent function. In this function you need to filter the departments you want based on the option selected. To make a test, call `/get/content/1` for example, directly from your browser, and check if it prints a viable select.

Comment: And it is a good idea to debug the javascript part to check if it fires `empty()` and `append(data)` functions too.

Comment: Hmm yes, guessing it might be something with the javascript, listener doesn't seem to react to any changes in the first select menu.

Comment: Are you already using jquery in your project? If you are not, you need to use it to call this function. Try to include it before `<script>` and check if it works

Comment: Yes, jquery is in the header of the master layout. When testing the url /package/create/142 it returns a new view with only the second select menu in it, it has the correct values though.

Comment: So the view is correct. The only thing you need to figure out is why `change` event is not firing.

Comment: Script code seems to work fine up until             $.get( '/home/package/create/' + value, function( data ) {
                $('#department').empty();
                $('#department').append(data);
            });

Comment: This line fires a GET request to the route that renders the view. So you have to use the same address you typed in your browser to test it. Is this `/home` correct?

Comment: Yes that's the url I'm using while redirecting serverside. No matter what url i pass in $get(), it does nothing for some reason.

Comment: Confirm if `var value = $(this).val();` has a correct value.

Comment: It has,             let value = $(this).val();
            alert(value); alerts item that is selected.

Comment: I can't figure out why it is not firing this GET request. Take a look here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Same here, it's the same url I'm using in the routes. When running `            $.get( "/home/package/create/" + value, function() {
            alert( "success" );
            })
            .done(function() {
                alert( "second success" );
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert( "finished" );
            });`  The error is returned.

Comment: If the route is working when you call it from the browser, I don't understand why it does not work using jquery.

Comment: `$('#company').change(function() {
            let value = $(this).val();
            alert(value);
           $.get( "http://localhost/test/test/public/home/package/create/" + value, function( data ) {
                alert('hmm');
                $('#department').empty();
                $('#department').append(data);
                alert('action performed');
            });
        });` Running this will fire the $get() function but does not get the view with create/value. Also the dependent select menu is empty.

Comment: Got the $get() function to fire, but the url does not update and the second select menu has nothing in it after function fires, looks bugged, doesn't open.

Comment: Try to change this `$('#second-select').append(data);` for this `$('#second-select').html(data);`

Comment: Data is empty when alerting or console logging or it sends the html for entire page depending on which url is used.